# ffmpeg for windows (directshow). Where to specify options?

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I think I've tried every conceivable permutation, but all I get are syntax errors.

I found this example:

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" output.mkv

And that works... but the result is a very low quality video.

Documentation for dshow suggests there are various options, including "video_size", however there is no documentation whatsoever on the syntax to use for options (in general or for that specific one) and no hints at valid input.  Can someone clue me in?

My goal is to screen capture at higher quality than the default provides.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
ffmpeg -{input1 options} -i input1 -{input2 options} -i input2
       -{output1 options} output1 -{output2 options} output2 ...
```

So, the directshow options for video will go before `-i video="screen-capture-recorder"` and for audio will go before `-i audio="virtual-audio-capturer"`

That said, you should show the full console output from one of your executions so that the issue here can be diagnosed.